# Is "blaring your nose into a tissue" an understandable/idiomatic sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Instead of saying "blowing your nose into a tissue" is it also okay to say "blaring your nose into a tissue?"

Example sentence:

> I fished out a balled tissue from my blouse's pocket and blared my
>   nose in it.

Comment: Are you making a loud trumpeting noise when you do this?  That’s the only way I can see blaring being used like that.  And I would call it a bit comedic.

Comment: You're making a very very thin pun. Or rather it will be taken that way.

Comment: If you are really referring to a trumpeting sound, I would use "trumpeted" instead of "blared".  "Blared isn't normally associated with blowing your nose, so people would likely fail to understand the connection.  But people know what an elephant sounds like, which is close enough to a loud, musical nose blowing, and that's referred to as "trumpeting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Blowing your nose into a tissue would be correct. Also, there should be no "'s" in blouse. Blouse pocket is correct.